# dependencies tree algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a jobs queue where each object may depend from one or multiple objects.

Can you suggest a C++ implementation of a dependancies tree algorithm that's able to detect and report circular dependencies and can be used to produce a visual representation easily ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting. The edges of the graph will be "depends on".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked for a C++ implementation, even the papers are interesting I do not want to deal with the details.
Here is exactly what I was looking for:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/graph/doc/file_dependency_example.html

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [Tarjan's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm), after modeling the problem as a graph (Objects re vertices, dependencies are edges).

Every [Strongly Connected Component (SCC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) will contain some circular depednecy in it, and every circular dependency will be a part of a non-trival SCC.

Comment: Will the downvoter explain why the answer is not useful in his opinion, so I can learn from my mistake?